# Pulling data from MySQL Server using PHP to display in JSON format

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, angularjs

I have seen a lot of similar questions and answers for this issue but nothing I try is working. So I thought I would ask as this is day 2 of my fight with this code to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

//check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$db=new PDO("mysqli:host=localhost;dbname=table", "username","password");

//initial query
$query = "Select * FROM table";

//execute query
try {
      $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
      $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
     }
catch (PDOException $ex) {
      $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
      die(json_encode($response));
     }

 // Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


 if ($rows) {
     $response["success"] = 1;
     $response["message"] = "Details Available!";
     $response["details"]   = array();

 foreach ($rows as $row) {
     $post             = array();
$post["ID"]  = $row["ID"];
     $post["cohort_name"] = $row["cohort_name"];
     $post["pin"]    = $row["pin"];
     $post["start_date"]  = $row["start_date"];

     //update our repsonse JSON data
     array_push($response["details"], $post);
    }


     // echoing JSON response
     echo json_encode($response);

   } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No Details Available!";
            die(json_encode($response));
       }

   ?>
```

My PHP is god awful and I got most of this if not all from reading what other people use. the error code I'm getting here is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in >'url to php page':15 Stack trace: #0 >'url to php page'(15): PDO->__construct('mysqli:host=loc...', >'username', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in >'url to php page' on line 15

Im using a MySQL server that is running wordpress, that I want to kinda work around and connect straight to the database because I'm setting up a separate user system for an Angular app (hence why I'm using JSON) I am already writing directly to the same sql table from the wordpress site using a .php page however the php page in question either throws some kind of error like the one above or doesn't throw anything up at all, just a blank page. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I generally don't use PDO, I prefer mysqli but although I'm not sure about your problem I can see the construct call to PDO is a little different from the one in the documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php where the code is something like this `$db=new PDO("'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1", "username","password");` and I think you won't need your first line where you call `mysqli_connect()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this part of your code is not necessary

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

//check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Also, the `PDO` connection made should be this way

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=table', $user, $pass);
```

make sure correct values are provided for the `table`, `$user` and `$pass`

You can read more about PDO connections [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: This has started making the server send back the data i need however it is now also throwing a notice of: "Undefined variable: query_params in 'url to php page' on line 18" I know what the error is, would it be best to remove that or where would I look to declare it?

Comment: change this `$stmt = $db->prepare($query); to $stmt = $db->query($query);`
and remove `$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);` from your code

Comment: That's sorted it!!! Thanks a lot man, you have helped me in a major way with this.

Comment: Just wanna state that if you don't "prepare" you statement and just go direct with the query and you use user obtained variables, you'll be exposed to a SQLinjection attack. If you don't use user obtained variables just the query is cool